# Azure Alert Creation Via terraform fails with error code 400

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-automation, alerts, terraform-provider-azure

While creating metric alert on storage account via terraform I am getting Error 400

I've gone through the documentation and corss-verified that the name I am using for alert creation is correct

```
resource "azurerm_metric_alertrule" "test" {
name                = "alerttestacc"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"

description = "An alert rule to watch the metric Used capacity"

enabled = true

resource_id = "${azurerm_storage_account.to_monitor.id}"
metric_name = "UsedCapacity"
operator    = "GreaterThan"
threshold   = 20
aggregation = "Total"
period      = "PT5M"

email_action {
    send_to_service_owners = false

    custom_emails = [
    "xyz@gmail.com",
    ]
}

webhook_action {
    service_uri = "https://example.com/some-url"

    properties = {
        severity        = "incredible"
        acceptance_test = "true"
    }
}
```

Expected: Alert should be created

Actual:

> azurerm_metric_alertrule.test:
>   insights.AlertRulesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to
>   request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
>   returned an error. Status=400 Code="UnsupportedMetric" Message="The
>   metric with namespace '' and name 'UsedCapacity' is not supported for
>   this resource id

Comment: why are you so sure that metric exists? it surely doesnt make a lot of sense to me

Comment: Azure documentation says that the metrics exist. [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_metric_alert.html)

Comment: CHeck this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/metric_alertrule.html)

Comment: On the second link there is a metric_name where a link of all metrics is given.

Comment: extensive list [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [azurerm_monitor_metric_alert](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_metric_alert.html) instead of [azurerm_metric_alertrule](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/metric_alertrule.html)  to create a **UsedCapacity** metric alert for the storage account. It is possible due to the different experiences between classic alerts and new alerts in Azure monitoring. Read alerts [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview).

This example works on my side.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "to_monitor" {
  name                     = "examplestorageaccount123"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  location                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "main" {
  name                = "example-actiongroup"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  short_name          = "exampleact"

  webhook_receiver {
    name        = "callmyapi"
    service_uri = "http://example.com/alert"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "test" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  scopes              = ["${azurerm_storage_account.to_monitor.id}"]
  description         = "Action will be triggered when the Used capacity is Greater than 777 bytes."

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    metric_name      = "UsedCapacity"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 777

  }

  action {
    action_group_id = "${azurerm_monitor_action_group.main.id}"
  }
}
```

[image]